Consider the following equation in real $x,y$: ${(x-2y-1)^2 + (4x-3y-4)^2 + (x-2y-1)(4x-3y-4)=0}$ Then the number of solutions $(x,y)$ is:
My workings for the above question. 
Consider the following equation in real $x,y$:
${(x-2y-1)^2 + (4x-3y-4)^2 + (x-2y-1)(4x-3y-4)=0}$
Clearly, the equation can be rewritten as:
$[(x-2y-1)+(4x-3y-4)]^2-(x-2y-1)(4x-3y-4)=0$
$or,[(x-2y-1)+(4x-3y-4)]^2=(x-2y-1)(4x-3y-4)$
$or,[5(x-y-1)]^2=(x-2y-1)(4x-3y-4)$
$or,25(x-y-1)^2=[(x-y-1)-y][4(x-y-1)+y]$
$or,25(x-y-1)^2=4(x-y-1)^2+(x-y-1)y+(x-y-1)4y-y^2$
$or,25=4+\dfrac{y}{(x-y-1)}-\dfrac{4y}{(x-y-1)}-\dfrac{y^2}{(x-y-1)^2}$
$or,21(x-y-1)^2+3y(x-y-1)+y^2=0$
$Substituting: [t=(x-y-1)]$
$or,21t^2+3yt+y^2=0$
$Taking, \Delta$
$or,9y^2-84y^2 \ge 0 [since, x,y ∈ \Bbb{R}]$
$or,y=0$
$Therefore, t=(x-y-1)=0$
$x=1$
Further, there exists two indistinct real roots of $x-y-1$, $(1,0)$ will be the only solution for $(x,y)$ in real.

I found this method much better, than the hit and trial one. Is it correct?

Welcome to MSE. A question should be written in such a way that it can be understood even by someone who did not read its title.

checked, same user spelling  but started two accounts, 1376607   and 1377026 . Ought to be merged if the user sticks around

by simply completing the square, $u^2 + uv + v^2 \geq \frac{3}{4}  v^2$   and $u^2 + uv + v^2 \geq \frac{3}{4}  u^2$ for real $u,v$

I would use $a = x-2y-1$ and $b=4x-3y-4$. The equations writes $a^2+b^2+ab=0$.
If $b=0$, the equation gives $a^2=0$, so $a=0, b=0$ is an acceptable solution:
$$\left \lbrace{a=0\\b=0}\right . \iff\left\lbrace{x-2y-1=0\\4x-3y-4=0}\right.
\iff\left\lbrace{4x-8y-4=0\\4x-3y-4=0}\right.\iff\left\lbrace{x-2y-1=0\\5y=0}\right.\iff\left\lbrace{x=1\\y=0}\right.$$
If $b\ne 0$, we can take $t=\frac a b$ and the equation gives $b^2\left(t^2+1+t\right)=0$ or $t^2+t+1=0$.
The discriminant is $\Delta = \frac {1^2 - 4\times 1\times 1}{2} =-\frac 3 2 <0$. So we will find no solution for $b\ne 0$
Conclusion: the initial equation accepts one single solution, the pair $x=1, y=0$.
As far as I am concerned, I find this way more direct that the one in the question.
